# how to automatically center the mouse cursor on new opened windows?

Tags: window-manager, focus, mouse-pointer

I cant find any option on `Unity tweak tool` neither compiz for that.
Google only shows info about that feature on WindowsOS.

related but about already opened windows: [Automatically move mouse to focused window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544492/automatically-move-mouse-to-focused-window)

I am using ubuntu 16.04.3 (but I am going to install 18.04.1 soon probably).

Comment: Provide information about the Ubuntu version and the desktop you are using by editing your question

Comment: "the desktop you are using" do you mean the hardware??? like in, this is not a notebook but an actual desk-top machine

Comment: Desktop refers to you using either Unity, or Gnome, or xfce. You indicated now Ubuntu 16.04. The default desktop there is Unity indeed. A possible solution may depend on the desktop environment and the window manager in use.

Comment: @vanadium oh I had already said unity from the beginning, despite I change to metacity quite often for performance, but as I understand some `xdotool` trick could work being WM independent :)

Comment: I could infer you used unity because you referred to Unity tweak tool, but you did not indicate specifically. Unity uses Compiz, and relies on, compiz as window manager, so when you are on metacity, you must be using another desktop. This might indeed be possible with xdotool, but that will require scripting.